# Do we have a replacement for expander wpf control in kendo ui or html wrapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, expander

Expander control is there in wpf , but do we have a replacement for it in kendo ui framework or in htmlhelper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading telerik docs i found the answer is `kendo panelbar`